# Conditionally declare variables as global inside a Python function

Tags: python, global-variables

I am developing a Python function of which the intermediate results should conditionally be accessible outside of the function, for plotting. It concerns > 20 variables of large size. To preserve memory I aim to only make the variables globally available in case the plotting is needed.

See the following code snippet I initially expected to work like desired:

```
def x():
        if True:
                global a
        a = 10
        return

x()
print(a)
```

**Expected result:** variable 'a' can be printed only if the if statement is executed.

**Actual result:** variable 'a' can always be printed.

I tried many things but cannot seem to achieve the desired behaviour. Proper programming would be to return the variables needed to the global scope, using 'return'. However, I do not know how to do that conditionally in a pretty way, with this many variables. Can anybody explain the behaviour I see, and suggest how to achieve the desired behaviour?

Comment: This seems like an exceptionally bad idea.

Comment: Why not just return something like `None` in the case where the data isn't needed? Or avoid calling the function at all if the data isn't needed (and that can be determined outside of the function before calling it)

Comment: @Carcigenicate I did not consider setting the variables to `None` after use, thanks for the suggestion. It does require setting the variables to the global scope first since otherwise they cannot be used outside of the function. The function returns an actual result besides the intermediates that conditionally need to be available outside of it. To call a different function would result in a lot of code duplication.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The determination of whether a variable is local or global is made when the function is being compiled, not when it runs. So this can't be dynamic.

You can solve it by using the `locals()` and `globals()` functions to access the different variable environments.

```
def x():
    env = locals()
    if <condition>:
        env = globals()
    env['a'] = 10
    return

x()
print(a)
```